# Controller method not found.In controller function not calling

Tags: php, laravel-4

### My Route.php

Route::controller('filemanagement', 'FilemanagementController');

### Function Name

public function getCouponData() {}

### File Name

uploadcoupondata.blade.php

But showing error:

Controller method not found.

Answer (score 0):

You have not assign any method for this route

**Route.php**

```
 Route::get('/filemanagement', 'FilemanagementController@getCouponData');
```

In your FilemanagementController file

```
class FilemanagementController extends Controller
{
  public function getCouponData() 
 {
     return view('uploadcoupondata');
 }

}
```

Comment: It is in 4.2 version